# How to update lodash to the latest version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash, jpm

I am using npm on the debian Linux flavor to install Jpm. But am getting errors about the versions of lodash installed (as follows)

```
test@localhost:~# npm install jpm --global
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
```

I have referred to few of the following links but am still unable to update the versions but still the issue persists.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/3.10.1-npm

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10573

Kindly suggest a solution to update the lodash version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After re-reading the question, I realised that the error is not in fact an error at all. What you are getting is a warning, saying that `jpm` uses lodash@2.4.1, which is deprecated, and no longer maintained.

After looking at the latest version of `jpm`, I noticed that the lodash dependency is for version `3.3.1` which should be fine.

This makes me think that either the jpm version that is being installed is old, or a jpm dependency relies on an older version of lodash, which would need to be updated to remove the warning.

Either way, this warning can be ignored, but if you must get rid of it, you will need to rebuild jpm (or possibly a jpm dependency and jpm), after updating the deprecated lodash reference.

Comment: Issue still persists.

Comment: root@localhost:~# npm uninstall -g lodash
unbuild lodash@3.10.1
root@localhost:~# npm install -g lodash
lodash@3.10.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lodash
root@localhost:~# npm install jpm --global
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.

Comment: hrm, so it looks like 3.10.1 is installing, but npm or jpm is seeing 2.4.1, weird. Maybe try uninstalling/reinstalling npm as well.

Comment: Done that too but no use.

Comment: Realised what the real problem is and updated my answer.

Comment: I have also have the same problem. Where can I find the file where lodash dependency is located? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me , using Windows 7 worked the following:

```
     npm i --save lodash
```

Documentation on lodash can be found here:

https://lodash.com/